# Dropdown select value is "undefined" when sent to the contoller action when editing in the modal form - jqgrid ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have a dropdown select column in jqgrid and I am populating the dropdown dynamically from the controller action. When I edit a row and select a value from the drop down and click Submit, it calls the controller action specified in the editurl but the drop down select column value is "undefined". I am stuck with this issue for a while, please any suggestions are really helpful. Below is my javascript code

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
url: '/Home/Update/',
datatype: 'json',
mtype: 'POST',
colNames: [‘Name’, ‘Position’],
colModel: [
{name: ' Name', index: ' Name', width: 50, align: 'center', editable: true,   
searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'cn']} },           
{name: ' Position ', index: ' Position ', width: 75, align: 'center', editable: true, 
 edittype: 'select', formatter:'select',
 editoptions: {
 dataUrl: '/Home/GetNames/',                        
 style: "width: 120px",

 buildSelect: function (data) {
   var response = $.parseJSON(data); 
   var s = '<select>';
   for (var i = 0; i < response.rows.length; i++) {
    var r = response.rows[i];
    s += '<option value="' + r.Id + '">' + r.cell[0] + '</option>';
   }
   return s + "</select>";
  }
},
searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'cn']} }],
  ondblClickRow: function (row_id) {
                    jQuery(this).jqGrid('editGridRow', row_id);
                },
                pager: jQuery('#list'),
                height: '100%',
                rowNum: 200,
                sortname: ‘Name’,
                sortorder: "asc",
                editurl: '/Home/Create'
            });
```

Comment: can u please show ur controller action method parameters?

Comment: @ Piyush: Which controller action should I post? Controller action for editurl? I think the problem is I am missing the syntax that I should use to send the selected drop down value to the controller action. Do you know what the syntax should be?

Comment: i never worked with dropdownnlist in jqgrid. anyhow i will look around and post some references, if i find sth good.

Comment: @ Piyush: Thanks a lot! Anyway, I think I have figured out the syntax, once it works completely, I will post the solution. Thanks again!

Comment: sure..post it and if it works fine, we will mark it as answer

Comment: @PiyushSardana: Please check the answer below, this is how I solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue with dataEvents property as below:

```
dataEvents: [{
            type: 'change',
            fn: function (e) {
            var i = $(e.target.value);
             }
       }]
```

Hope this helps someone.